# revoke all privileges, grant option not working?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to revoke privileges from a given user, say `mysqluser1`. I try, as root, `revoke all privileges, grant option for mysqluser1@localhost;`, then I `flush privileges`. When I check grants, I see that `mysquser1` still has privileges. What am I doing wrong?

Below is the excerpt in question:

```
mysql> show grants for mysqluser1@localhost;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for mysqluser1@localhost                                                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'mysqluser1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*ALPHANUMSTRINGHERE' |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> revoke all privileges, grant option from mysqluser1@localhost;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show grants for mysqluser1@localhost;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for mysqluser1@localhost                                                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'mysqluser1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*ALPHANUMSTRINGHERE' |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `USAGE` privilege specifier stands for "no privileges." It is used at the global level with GRANT to modify account attributes such as resource limits or SSL characteristics without affecting existing account privileges.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html

Answer (score 3):

@spencer was faster, but I was also going to ask, if you are trying to get rid of all privileges, then why do you need the user?

To remove a user account entirely, use DELETE. As of MySQL 4.1.1, you can also use DROP USER to remove users

Comment: does that also drop the grants for the user?

Comment: Yes, DROP USER user; Removes privilege rows for the account from all grant tables. Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-user.html